# Approximate Solution to Damped Nonlinear Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, computational-physics, perturbation-theory, oscillators

The Nonlinear Damped Pendulum Equation

$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{b}{m}\dot{\theta}+\frac{g}{l}\sin(\theta)=0$

isn’t exactly solvable unlike the Nonlinear Pendulum as there’s no constant of motion namely Energy which allows the Equation to be reduced to an Integral unlike the undamped case. Is it possible to get approximate solutions to this equation via Perturbation Theory with this trick the same way you can for the regular Nonlinear Pendulum.

$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{b}{m}\dot{\theta}+\frac{g}{l}(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{6})=0$

Where the $-\frac{g}{l}\frac{\theta^3}{6}$ is treated as a Perturbation to the regular damped Harmonic Oscillator.

My question is has anyone tried this method and is this a viable method for the damped Nonlinear Pendulum or other methods are required. If so could you link or recommend some resources which discuss Perturbation theory applied to the Damped Nonlinear Pendulum.

Comment: There's a really nice write-up here: https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Sophmore%20Class%20Notes%202007/Chapter%205.pdf

Comment: You might also look up the unforced Duffing oscillator.